# How can I check that a web property exists on a SharePoint web site?

Tags: properties, sharepoint-2010, web

I need to check that a web property exists on a SharePoint web site using Client Object Model.

```
SP.Web web = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
clientContext.Load(web.AllProperties, p=> p[propertyName]);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This code fails, because there is no property with the name **propertyName**. How can I check, that this property exists before trying to load it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Site spSite = clientContext.Site;
clientContext.Load(spSite);
Web spWeb = spSite.RootWeb;
clientContext.Load(spWeb, w => w.AllProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
var allProperties = spWeb.AllProperties;
clientContext.Load(allProperties);

// next line checks if property exists
if (!spWeb.AllProperties.FieldValues.ContainsKey("SiteType"))
{
    spWeb.AllProperties["SiteType"] = "BuildWork";
    spWeb.Update();
}
clientContext.Load(spWeb, w => w.AllProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```